# How do I get the same version of Microsoft Outlook that I use on my work machine on my personal machine?

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, windows-11, user-interface

My work laptop has recently received an upgrade to Windows 11. Outlook has also updated and has a new UI (which I really like, which is why I want to have this version on my personal computer):

[image]
*New Outlook interface on work machine.*

On my personal machine, I have Microsoft Office 2021 Professional installed and have also upgraded to Windows 11. The Outlook interface has not changed:

[image]
*Current Outlook UI on personal computer*

However, there is a switch in the top right of the screen suggesting to 'Try the new Outlook':

[image]
*Try new Outlook switch*

Upon clicking this, the UI is changed, but does not resemble the UI of the Outlook that I use with my work laptop:

[image]
*New Outlook UI on personal computer*

Please could somebody please suggest how I can get Outlook displaying with the UI that my work laptop uses?

I've searched online, but I cannot find one example of the UI of Outlook that my work machine uses. I suspect it might not be the new version, but just a different design, but there is nothing to suggest that in the settings.

EDIT:

Added a screenshot of collapsing the Ribbon which hasn't updated the UI.

[image]

Thanks,
James

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145894/discussion-on-question-by-jrygz-how-do-i-get-the-same-version-of-microsoft-outlo); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @DavidPostill weren't the comments for clarification? I thought they were

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design changes you're looking for is called ***Office visual refresh*** which gives the Microsoft Office applications a Windows 11 Style look.

The details are in the announcement [**The new look of Office**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/the-new-look-of-office-a6cdf19a-b2bd-4be1-9515-d74a37aa59bf).

This look is available both in Build 16327.20214 and in the newer Build 16327.20248.

The odd thing about enabling it, as detailed in the Microsoft article is:

> you can’t use [Outlook] to switch the visual refresh on and off. If you switch on the visual refresh in Word, Excel, PowerPoint, or OneNote, it will also be available in Outlook

So to enable it:

1. Open one of the other Microsoft Office applications (Word, Excel, PowerPoint, or OneNote)
2. Click on the **Trumpet icon** next to window controls, and toggle the **Try it now** in the ***Visual Refresh Preview*** pane that opens:
   [image]
3. It will tell you that you need to restart the application for the change to take effect. Close that other office application, and restart Outlook

You should now have the Windows 11 Style look in Outlook.

Comment: I've managed to resolve it, and it is similar to your answer. I opened Microsoft Word (for the first time since I upgraded to Office 21 Pro). I didn't see the (1) icon, but it updated to the Windows 11 Style automatically upon opening. I then opened Outlook and that had updated as well. I believe this answer is the solution, so I shall mark it as such. Thanks for the help @Yisroel Tech.

Answer (score -1):

To learn more about the new Outlook for Windows, you can check out [the latest blog post](https://insider.office.com/blog/starting-to-support-third-party-accounts-in-new-outlook-for-windows-preview). According to the official documentation, currently available to Insiders.

[The Microsoft 365 Insider program](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/insider/compare-channels) provides early access to Microsoft 365 Apps features through two channels:

- Beta Channel
- Current Channel (Preview)

Hope above can help you!